# Gmock Set Reference Based On Another Parameter

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have an API that looks like: `bool api(Object object, ObjectID& objectID)`

I want to use ON_CALL to mock the API so that it takes takes a member from object and set it to objectID and return true. But I can’t figure out how to use SetArgReferee and access the other param with it.

Comment: Are you sure the method is not `bool api(Object& object, ObjectID objectID)`? As it stands, the mutation would be performed on a **copy** on `object`, making your mock function a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a lambda to the gmock hooks.

For example using `WillByDefault`, you should be able to do:

```
ON_CALL(foo, api).WillByDefault([](Object& object, ObjectID objectID) {
      object.some_member = objectID;
});
```